# Testing Shrine gem return error undefined method `set_derivatives'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, shrine

I am trying to test uploads through Shrine.
I have Minio and followed this tutorial https://shrinerb.com/docs/testing#test-data

Yet `FactoryBot.lint` returns the following error from the TestModule code provided in the link:

```
profilepic - undefined method `set_derivatives' for #<Shrine::Attacher:0x000055ee893dfe00 @file=#<Shrine::UploadedFile storage=:store id="8aa14e79342fde0077fd48f1035f56c3" metadata={"size"=>576152, "mime_type"=>"image/jpeg", "filename"=>"profile_pic.jpg"}>, @cache=:cache, @store=:store, @context={}, @previous=nil, @column_serializer=Shrine::Plugins::Column::JsonSerializer, @model_cache=true, @model=nil, @destroy_block=nil, @promote_block=nil, @errors=[]> (NoMethodError)
# /home/maxence/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/factory_bot-6.2.1/lib/factory_bot/linter.rb:13:in `lint!'
# /home/maxence/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/factory_bot-6.2.1/lib/factory_bot.rb:70:in `lint'
# ./spec/support/factory_bot.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any idea what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from the error it looks like `derivatives` plugin is not loaded. https://shrinerb.com/docs/plugins/derivatives

Add this to the test module

```
Shrine.plugin :derivatives
```

Comment: Good guess Alex. I added it and the error is now gone. It sets the derivatives hash. Yet then I get error `undefined method `to_hash' for "{\"id\":\"2265e30ce365faa5b7087470e29c346c\",\"storage\":\"s etc .. ` I am probably missing another plugin, will investigate..